# Kth largest sum of contigous array

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, stl, set

I tried to write a program to find the K-th largest sum of contiguous subarray within the array of numbers which has negative and positive numbers in C++.For ex:
Input: a[] = {20, -5, -1} 
         k = 3
Output: 14.
Explanation: All sum of contiguous 
subarrays are (20, 15, 14, -5, -6, -1) 
so the 3rd largest sum is 14.

This is without using a min heap approach. 
I am facing run-time issues.Can anyone help out?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<iterator>


using namespace std;
int greatSum(int a[],int n,int num,int k){
    set<int> s;
    set<int>::iterator it;
    if(num==0){
        it=s.begin();
        advance(it,k-1);
        return *it;
    }
    if(num!=0){
        int itr=n-num+1;
        for(int i=0;i<itr;i++){
            int sum=0;
            for(int j=0;j<num;j++)
                sum+=a[j];
            s.insert(sum);
        }

        return greatSum(a,n,num-1,k);

    }

}
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    int k;
    cin>>k;
    cout<<greatSum(a,n,n,k);


}
```

Comment: You'll need to use a sliding-window technique, to avoid recomputing sums.

Comment: You seem to expect that `s` preserves its value between `greatSum` calls. This is not the case. It's a local variable - every call has its own copy, and starts with an empty set. Then  `advance(it,k-1)` exhibits undefined behavior unless `k-1 == 0`, and in any case `*it` exhibits undefined behavior for sure.